# Values of $\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

For  $$f(x)={\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x}}$$ where $ x\not=-1$ decide which *values $f(x)$ could take*.

Should I take the limit as $x$ → -1 in each direction? And then as x → ± $\infty$? If so, I'm not sure of how that would be done.

Comment: You are essentially asking for a range? You should take the limit to see what happens, also it wouldn't hurt to use a graphing tool to see if there are extremes. Then use the derivative to verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the range of the function $f$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x}.
$$

Note that $e^{-x}$ is always positive. And that 
$$
\lim_{x\to -1^-} f(x) = -\infty
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to -1^+} f(x) = \infty.
$$

Note that 
$$
f'(x) = \frac{-e^{-x}(1+x) - e^{-x}}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{-2e^{-x} - xe^{-x}}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{-e^{-x}(2+ x)}{(1+x)^2}.
$$
so $f$ is increasing on the interval $(-\infty, -2]$ and decreasing on $[-2, -1) $ and $(-1,\infty)$. So we have a local maximum at $x=-2$.

Now also note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ so $f$ attains all values in the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Now $f$ is only negative when $x < -1$ and has a local maximum at $x=-2$, so the interval $(-\infty, f(-2)]$ is in the range.

In all you get the range is $(-\infty, f(-2)] \cup (0,\infty) = \mathbb{R} \setminus (f(-2), 0]$.